# Deshuffle text with C

Tags: c, sorting

I wanted to get an opinion here. Would it be possible to write a C program that deshuffles a text file? What do I mean by that? Say I have the following data in a textfile:

```
1  X
4  T
3  Z
2  L
```

And I wanted to deshuffle it and output another file as so:

```
1  X
2  L
3  Z
4  T
```

Such that all of the data following the number is preserved with the actual index number. Do know that I have 40,500 shuffled entities, so that should probably be taken into account since that could take a long time if the program needs to loop through all of the entities for *each* entity...And I only used letters for representation. The actual data files don't have letters, but rather have **floats**. Sorry if this causes any confusion

So, bottom line, would this be possible with C? And if so, could I get a hint at where to start? I could obviously input all of the textfile data into an array `dat[][]`, but how should I deshuffle it then?

Thanks!
Amit

Comment: And instead of letters, they are all float numbers...I just used letters in my representation

Comment: If you want us to do your homework, at least tag it as such.

Comment: It's not homework, it's for my research. If you don't want to give any input, please don't. I was just asking for an opinion to see if it's even possible.

Comment: Of course it's possible. The better question is have you tried?

Comment: No, hence the question regarding an opinion.

Comment: "Deshuffle" is calling "sorting". Once you know the correct terms, you're guaranteed to find a standard library that provides this functionality.

Comment: @Cody: Yes that is true. I'm still learning...Hopefully in the future I'll be able to come up with synonyms / more appropriately correct terms to help me find a built-in function to cut down on coding as well as process time !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just use [`sort -n`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) instead of writing a program.

Comment: So I came across that. Does that keep the data following the index number?

Comment: @Amit: It will sort the lines of the file based on the numerical value at the beginning of each line. So yes, it will keep the data with each number.

Comment: That's excellent! I will give it a try, and if it works, you'll most certainly get the check. That would also mean I just wasted an hour writing that program :(

Comment: @Amit: Well, it's not a total waste if you learned something. 8v)

Comment: @Amit: Just make the check payable to Fred Larson and send it to... just kidding. Out of curiosity, how long did `sort -n` take?

Comment: @Fred: Very very quick. for 40,500 entities, less than 5 minutes. My program took 30.

Comment: @Amit: Excellent. Great example of [Taco Bell Programming](http://teddziuba.com/2010/10/taco-bell-programming.html).

Answer (score 3):

Look up qsort, its part of stdlib.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the largest index in the file and there are no holes (i.e. all indices are present), you can create an array of that size, then as you read each line of the file, put the data into the correct location in the array. When you're done reading the file, your array will have all the elements in the correct order.

Comment: Interesting. This sounds like a good idea. I will try to implement it now.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a `vector< pair<int,float[4]> >` and just sort it using STL.

Just noticed a `c` tag.... But C idea is about the same:

Build an array with the data:

```
struct pair
{
    int idx;
    float val[4];
}

pair *data;
```

And then just sort it.

Comment: Hey, sorry about the confusion. The data files actually contain and index number and are followed by 4 float numbers, no characters.

Comment: The array with the data is already built. I have it set to `dat[i][j]` where i is the ith row and `j` is the `jth` column

Comment: In your case it is not so easy to sort 2D array, but much easier to sort 1D array. Take a look at `qsort` function.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to sort a 2D array because I need to maintain the data following the index

Comment: Why can't you create a 1D array of structures as I described in my answer?

Comment: @Elalfer: To be honest, I'm very new to C and I'm not that familiar with structures.

Comment: So, it is a good time and task to learn them ;) You can read for example here http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/structures.html

Comment: Will do! Thanks a lot for your help and suggestion, I will look at structures as a possibility for this program. +1 for your help.

Answer (score 0):

For those interested, I ended up using a series of loops to write this program, the code is show below. The only downside of it is that if my `nrow` variable is equal to 40,500, this program can take as long as 30 mins to run on a 3GHz dual core computer. I'm sure there are ways to optimize it, though at least it does what I want...for now.

Here's the code:

```
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdio.h"

// Deshuffle the output files of the bond/swap mode

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 4) {
        printf("\ndeshuffle usage: [number of chains] [number of atoms] [.dat file] \n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int i,j,k,l;
    int nch = atoi( argv[1] );
    int ns = atoi( argv[2] );
    double **in_dat, **s_dat, dm1;

    int nrow = ns*nch;

    in_dat = (double**) calloc(nrow, sizeof(double*));
    s_dat = (double**) calloc(nrow, sizeof(double*));
    for (i=0; i<nrow; i++) {
        in_dat[i] = (double*) calloc(6, sizeof(double));
        s_dat[i] = (double*) calloc(6, sizeof(double));
        for (j=0; j<6; j++)
            in_dat[i][j] = 0.0;
            s_dat[i][j] = 0.0;
    }

    // store input data into 2D array in_dat
    FILE *inp;
    inp = fopen( argv[3], "r" );

    for (i=0; i<nrow; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<6; j++) {
            fscanf(inp, "%lf", &dm1);
            in_dat[i][j] = dm1;
        }
    }

    fclose(inp);

    // Sort data in s_dat based on comparison with in_dat
    k=0; 
    while (k < (nrow)) {
        for (i=0; i<nrow; i++) {
            for (l=0; l<nrow; l++) {
                if (in_dat[l][0] == (k+1)) {
                    for (j=0; j<6; j++) {
                        s_dat[i][j] = in_dat[l][j];
                    }
                    k++;
                    break;                  
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Write sorted data to file

    FILE *otp;
    otp = fopen("results.out", "w");

    for (i=0; i<nrow; i++) {
        for (j=0; j<6; j++) {
            fprintf(otp, "%lf \t", s_dat[i][j]);
            if (j==5)
                fprintf(otp, "\n");
        }
    }

    fclose(otp);

    printf("\n Done. \n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I wrote a program to generate 40,000 floats in random order. The system sort on my computer took a little less than 100 milliseconds to sort them and put the sorted output in a file, about 3 seconds to dump it to the screen.

Comment: @Catcall: Impressive. I've modified my program to take less than 10 seconds to sort 45,000 floats and output the file. Though still, the `sort -n` command is faster.